# Steam won't start

Tags: steam

When I try to start Steam I get this error.

```
$ steam
[2020-09-06 18:07:31] Startup - updater built Apr  9 2019 22:48:20
ILocalize::AddFile() failed to load file "public/steambootstrapper_english.txt".
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
cat: '/home/david/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime.tar.xz.part*': No such file or directory
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
xz: (stdin): File format not recognized
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
find: ‘/home/david/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime’: No such file or directory
```

Comment: After the complete removal of all the steam maps. I installed from the site (vulcan) that did not work. So I installed form the package manager... same issue...